# What happens if i don't call optional super methods or constructors in extended classes?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Lets think about Asynctask class.

It has  overrideable methods such as *onPreExecute*,*onProgressUpdate* etc.
Compiler does not give error if i dont add super.'method-name' etc. So should i do it or not? What is the benefit of calling (or not calling) super methods *when we dont have to call*

When we think of extending EditText class, after your customization you need to call super constructor for sure.

**NOTE:** I am talking about optional super calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general, and as a rule in object oriented programming:  unless you have a good reason to break it, and you know exactly what's the super class method implementation all about,   you should always call the super class methods.

in the specific case of `AsyncTask` - it is not required to call the super class method, simply because it does not doing any code.

opposite example:  if you will not call the super methods of an `Activity` callbacks such as `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` you will break entirely the activity, and probably nothing will work.  that's because the super class implementation of this methods doing tons of stuff required from each activity.

so the conclusion is that if you are not the writer of the base class - look for documentation providing any hints about methods you which to override in order know how, and if at all you should call the super class methods.

Answer (score 1):

As they are empty methods you do not have to call them. They are just there for you to use for overriding.

Comment: What about extending EditText class. You need to call super at the end after you customize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call the superclass's method, then...the superclass's method doesn't get called. Whether that's a problem depends entirely on what the superclass method does. If it's optional, as you say, then call it if you need to (e.g., your logic requires whatever it does) and don't call it if you don't.

If the superclass's method is *empty*, the only reason for coding the call to it would be if you rebased your class. E.g., suppose you had `A` as a base with an empty `foo` method, and `B` derived from it (`class B extends A`). Later, you want to be able to change it to `class B extends SpecialA` where `SpecialA` is a special version of `A` where `foo` does something. If you've left the supercall out of `B`'s `foo`, you'll have to remember to add it. If you included it in the first place, you won't have to remember to add it.

(The only supercall that *has* to happen is a call to the superclass's *constructor* when constructing the object, but if you leave that out, the compiler will supply a call to the zero-args version [e.g., `super()`]. But that's a constructor, not a method.)